# How to use RegEx to query cosmos records?

Tags: regex, azure-cosmosdb

I want to use regex, [\b\d{10}\b](https://regex101.com/r/4rxyaV/1) (matches exact 10 digits), in my cosmos query.

i.e., this is how my records looks like in a container.

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "stockNumber": "1001234567"
}

{
  "id": "pqr",
  "stockNumber": "200"
}

{
  "id": "xyz",
  "stockNumber": "200111"
}
```

and when I run following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    c
WHERE
    RegexMatch(c.stockNumber, @"\b\d{10}\b")
```

I get this error.

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "One of the input values is invalid."
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "stockNumber": "1001234567"
}
```

Regex is working as expected. Here, is the [working example of regex](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ir0Hek).

How can I achieve the desired result?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/regexmatch

Comment: Why do you have `@` before the regexp string? None of the examples on the `RegexMatch()` documentation page use that.

Comment: I guess you might be trying to use C# verbatim string syntax for some reason?

Comment: Are you looking for "contains ten digits surrounded by word boundaries" as your current regex would imply or "is ten digits"? In data explorer `RegexMatch(c.stockNumber, "\\b\\d{10}\\b")` and `"\\A\\d{10}\\z"` both work for me anyway

Comment: @Barmar, I simply added C# verbatim as `Martin Smith` mentioned. I was trying different variations to make this work.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am looking for exact 10 digits. `RegexMatch(c.stockNumber, "\\b\\d{10}\\b")` worked for me. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CosmosDB's SQL dialect does not support C# style verbatim strings.

Additionally the regex you added to the question would match strings like `abc 1234567890` - which is wrong semantics for what you need.

It is also potentially less efficient (definitely can't use an index seek unless there is an anchor for beginning of string) but I'm not sure in practice if CosmosDB will see the character class for the initial character and just seek on the range `0-9`.

In data explorer in the Emulator the following does what you need (`passes` returns `true` - all other test cases `false`)

```
SELECT VALUE {
    passes: RegexMatch("1234567890", "^\\d{10}$"),
    fail0: RegexMatch("123456789", "^\\d{10}$"),
    fail1: RegexMatch("01234567890", "^\\d{10}$"),
    fail2: RegexMatch(" 1234567890", "^\\d{10}$"),
    fail3: RegexMatch(" 1234567890 ", "^\\d{10}$")
}
```

Comment: Understood. `"^\\d{10}$"` gives me exact 10 digits match. What if I need the opposite of that? Meaning, give me all where stockNumber is not 10 digits. i.e., `abc123`,  `abc-123 45`, `01234567890` etc.

Comment: `WHERE NOT RegexMatch`